# Customising subtitle when splitting up table on more pages in PROC REPORT

Tags: split, sas, customization, title, proc-report

I'm trying to split a tabel from PROC REPORT into two (as it is to big to fit onto one page). I found (thank you google) two ways of doing the split, both based on a dummy variabel ('pgbrk') indicating where to split. My problem is now that I would like to add different subtitles to the table indicating which part of the table we are looking at. I've added a reproducible example below. In the first one I can add a line (which I can define my self) to the table, and in the second I have an auto generated sub-title. Can anyone help be to combine the two into a customized sub-title?

Thank you!

/Kira

```
data test;
infile datalines;
input name $ sex $ pgbrk;
return;
datalines;
Anne F  1
Bengt M 1
Camilla F 1
Dan M 1
Emil M 2
Frode M 2
Gertrud F 2
Hedvig F 2
Ida F 2
;    
run;

proc report data = test nowd ;
  title '1) Use PGBRK in BREAK AFTER';
  column pgbrk name sex ;
  define pgbrk / group noprint;
  define name/group;
  define sex/display;
  break after pgbrk / page;
  compute before _page_;
  disp_line = 'Table part: '||trim(put(pgbrk,2.0));
  line disp_line $20.;
  endcomp;
run;

proc report data=test nowd;
  by pgbrk;
  title '2) Use PGBRK in BY PGBRK=#byval1';
  column name sex;
  define name/group;
  define sex/display;
run;
```

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you want to do exactly.  What are you having trouble with here?  What's wrong with either of the above solutions?

Comment: Well, both solutions above works and gives a readable table, but I want to be able to change the subtitle saying either in the top of the table (first exampel) **Table part: 1**, or in the second **pgbrk = 1**. Am I making sense?